# Changing vCenter servers

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I have a vCenter 4.0 U1 server with a few Connection Manager servers connected to it. I need to change the vCenter server to another 4.0 U1. Can I simply change the vCenter server info in the Connection Manager without interupting any of my VDI Pools?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you need to re-register the CM servers if you move vCenter. This is an old unanswered question... not sure its relevant; but thought I would try.